# In Practice, Should all the objects of a class be made to have same number of attributes?

Tags: python, class, coding-style

Which is the better coding practice?

Sample the following (written in python):

```
class sampleClass:
   def __init__( self, filter ):   #filter is a string
      self.indexed = False #no
      filterTokens = filter.split()
      if ( filterTokens[0].isdigit ):
         self.indexed = True #yes
      else:
         return
      self.action = filterTokens[1]
      self.protocol = filterTokens[2]
      self.validity = True #valid
      if ( self.protocol == 'ip' )
         #something
      elif ( self.protocol == 'tcp' )
         #someOtherThing
      else:
         self.validity = False #Invalid
```

Now, if the first *token* in *filter* is not a number, the object of the class will have just one attribute - *indexed*.

The above class could have hundreds of attributes. In such a case which is a better coding practice -

To have same number of attributes for all the objects. (i.e define all the attributes at the top of the constructor, giving them some default value or another)

Or

The other way (as in the sample above)

Eg.

```
filter = '10 permit ip 10.10.10.0/28 20.20.20.0/28'
obj = sampleClass(filter)
```

Comment: Why are you using `0` and `1` rather than `True` and `False`? Is the whole of `filter` just a series of flags for boolean attributes? Do you have defaults for all of the attributes? Are there some that depend on others? When will you be accessing the attributes?

Comment: @jonrsharpe filter is an information string. Based on which the attributes are to be initialized. Not all attributes depend on one another. If I don't have default for all attributes, they can just be _"n/a"_ or something of the sort.

Comment: Could you provide a couple of slightly less minimal examples of `filter` and what should happen with it?

Comment: Why are you doing that init. Just store the filter string. Why is it a  string anyway?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Because the the information in _filter_ is to be used later, not as a string but in pieces. I wouldn't care if the string was not indexed, it only bothers me if the string was indexed.
To store the string as it is will lead to operational complications later. I seek an opinion on the preferable coding-style.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have given the example. See if it helps detail my question.

Comment: @HindK and what will `filter` look like if it's first item isn't a digit? An empty string? Something else? Why would you create the object with `indexed==False`?

Comment: Don't see what deferring splitting filter makes aside from a more complex harder to test and change implementation. Given you are always passing one argument, premise of your question seems somewhat broke

Comment: Hmm just read your edit, have you considered making filter an object in it's own right? I would...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real difference is in the code that's *using* your class. It seems likely that any such code would look like:

```
if sample_instance.indexed and sample_instance.valid: # 'valid' reads better
    protocol = sample_instance.protocol
```

so it doesn't really matter whether, in the case `.indexed == False`, whether or not `.valid` or `.protocol` exist or have any particular values.

If you want the calling code to get an attribute back (even if just `None`) whatever the case, you could always implement `__getattr__` to `return None` for any attributes that aren't directly resolved.

---

I would suggest moving the string parsing out of `__init__`, though; consider having a class method that does that instead. Also, you are mixing different bits of logic within the same method. Compare to:

```
class SampleClass(object):

    PROTOCOLS = {'ip': do_this_to_ip, 
                 'tcp': but_this_to_tcp}

    def __init__(self, indexed=False, action=None, protocol=None):
        self.indexed = indexed
        self.action = action
        self.protocol = protocol

    @property
    def valid(self):
        return self.protocol in self.PROTOCOLS 

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, filter_): # avoid shadowing the built-in
        filter_ = filter_.split()
        if not filter_[0].isdigit():
            return cls()
        return cls(True, filter_[1], filter_[2])
```

Which would be used like:

```
>>> sample = SampleClass.from_string("10 permit ip")
>>> sample.valid
True
>>> sample.protocol
'ip'
>>> sample2 = SampleClass.from_string("foo bar")
>>> sample2.valid
False
```

---

Finally, a broader question you should consider is: *if instances are going to be so different from each other, should they really be the same class?*